# Python script to read a text file and write into a csv file

Tags: python

I have a text file in which each row has multiple words (which I want to consider as columns). Now I want to read all the data from this text file and create a csv file with rows and columns. I am written the code till here -

```
import csv
f=open("text.txt", "r")
reader=csv.reader(f)
offile=open("output.csv","wb")
writer=csv.writer(offile,delimiter='\t',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in reader:
 ........

f.close()
offile.close()
```

I am not able to understand how to divide each row into columns and write this columns and rows back while writing a csv file? I am a newbie to python, so a good example I will be very greatful.

Thanks

Comment: please post a linkt to test.txt if you want someone to be able to give you more than passing help

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the lines via a regular expression:

```
line = "Foo bar baz quux"
import re
pieces = re.split("\s+", line)
print pieces
```

This results in

`['Foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux']`

The regular expression used above matches for multiple (+) white space characters (\s)

Comment: Do you know that split() without argument is equivalent to split("\s+") but faster?

Comment: why would you do this instead of `line.split()` ??

Comment: Question author didn't specify much detail on how they wanted to split, other than "divide rows into columns".  Yeah, there's a bunch of different ways you can split by whitespace.  I did it with the re module specifically to draw attention to the use of a regular expression.  That comes with it flexibility to split in any number of different ways.  The beginner nature of the question led me to believe that we couldn't take it for granted he/she knows what regular expressions are.

Comment: The input text file has random different types of data in rows like -  
data1    data2   data3    data4   data5   data6 data7

All I want is to consider all the 'data' as columns in a single row and write it as a single row into a csv file. Hope this helps more

Comment: @user3486471 are you saying it has strange delimiters that separate fields?  Do you know what they are?  Is this columnar data where say the first 10 columns is one field?   For follow up questions, you might want to pastebin a sample of the data you're trying to process.

Comment: @user3486471 that text looks like it's whitespace delimited.  The regular expression I provided should work to split the row into columns.  You may want to just use the split method as described in other comments if you want it to run slightly faster, but either way will work.

Comment: how do I write these pieces into a csv file? I do not want to print them. I want to construct rows with these 'data' fields as my columns in csv file

Comment: So you use split as we described above to split a line into its individual fields.  You end up with an array called "fields".   If you then write this line of code:   print(",".join(fields)) then it will join all the items in the array with the comma character, and you'll have one line of CSV

Comment: +1 for recognising the need for `re` before the OP clarified what his delimiters were

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
data = open("test.txt").read()
lines_of_data = data.splitlines()
writer=csv.writer(offile,delimiter='\t',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
writer.writerows(map(lambda line:re.split("\s\s\s\s+",line.strip()),lines_of_data))
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance - but how do I get this 'data'. All I have is an input text file 'f' and an output csv file 'offile'?

Comment: data is an example of `f.read()` sin ce you never showed us what your input file looks like I assumed its contents looked something like my `data` variable

Comment: please post a whole textfile  or at least several rows

Comment: yeah it would be better if you could provide a link(to download) ... I think pastebin is normalizing your whitespace to normal spaces(I assume the delimiter is tabs)

Comment: the link is correctly showing my rows. That is the concern here that the delimiter is not tabs correctly, each field is seperated from it's preceding field by normal spaces.

Comment: thank you Joran Beasley . I wrote the code - import csv import re data = open("text.txt").read() offfile = open("out.csv", "wb") lines_of_data=data.splitlines() writer =csv.writer(offfile,delimiter='\t',quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL) writer.writerows(map(lambda line:re.split("\s\s\s\s+",line.strip()),lines_of_data)) I open the output csv using microsoft excel and all the fields in a single row. Is this correct? I thought that each field would be shown in different column?

Comment: you must have excell setup to use "\t" as the delimiter (its normally a comma ...)

Comment: if you look at the file you will see that each field is its own quoted column with a tab separating columns ... so you need to tell excell that tabs are your delimiter ,  or just use `writer=csv.writer(offile)` to use a standard comma separator

Comment: ok. I will do that. And also I want to add 'column names' at the begining for each of the column in a row like 
Col_Name1  Col_Name2 Col_Name3
data1       data2    data3

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
data = open('test.txt').read()
lines_of_data = data.splitlines()
tmp = []
for i in range(len(lines_of_data)):
    tmp.append(lines_of_data[i].split())    
data_df = pd.DataFrame(tmp) 
data_df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add a paragraph or two summarizing how your code addresses the question, or perhaps  explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks.