# Read output of a csv file and write it to a text file using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, text

I have a python file where I get user inputs for student database and I have written them as a csv file. I couldn't get the links in google to read the csv output and write those csv output to a text file.

Sample Csv output:

```
Name    Roll no Age Mark1   Mark2
a        1       2    3       4
g        3      54    54      3
```

import csv

```
with open('abc.csv','r') as f:
    reader=csv.dictreader(f)
    for row in reader:
        output=('xyz.txt','r')
```

I know how to read a csv file but I don't know how to write those contents to a text file

Comment: please google your question first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script to read a text file and write into a csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794520/python-script-to-read-a-text-file-and-write-into-a-csv-file)

Comment: To all, my question is ow to read the csv output and write it to a text file and not reading text file and writing it to csv

Comment: if you believe your question is unique, then please provide your code. show us what you have already done.

Comment: so, you want to write each row of csv to the text file 'xyz.txt'?

Comment: Yes. Each row in csv file along with the headers needs to be written to text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
import csv

output=open('xyz.txt','w')

with open('abc.csv',"rt", encoding='ascii') as f:
for row in f:
    output.write(row)
```

Comment: For loop needs to be intended. Ascii encoding wasnt needed for my file. Please edit them.

Comment: Can you explain why you gave mode as rt and ascii encoding? I can understand the rest of codes. Sorry I'm a beginner in python

Comment: sure, but I bet you can google things, the answer to your question is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051062/open-files-in-rt-and-wt-modes

Comment: About, ascii encoding, just in case, maybe you will need it.

Comment: Thanks :) How to get the contents of entire row in csv file when i select a particular roll no?

Comment: use the number of the row, or the value. But for the row number solution you will need a row counter.

Comment: can you explain it with a sample code considering rollno 1 or 2 from input ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755587/using-python-to-write-specific-lines-from-one-file-to-another-file check this link

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code Indentation and comments are inline

1. Read CSV file
2. Manipulate Fields
3. Write to file

> Blockquote

```
import csv

#Open file with "w"(write), the file will create automatically.
file = open("/home/xyz/testfile.txt", "w")
#Open CSV file to read CSV, note: reading and write file should be under "with"
with open('/home/xyz/Desktop/ta_cta.csv') as csvFile:
    #Read CSV
    readCsv = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in readCsv:
        #Get Values and manupilate in the file.write
        Id = row[0]
        Id1 = row[1]
        #Write CSV you need format it to string if the value is an int
        file.write("UPDATE Schema.TableName SET Column1="+str(Id1)+" where Column2="+str(Id)+";\n")
#You Must Close the FIle after writing it.
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn python csv module firstly.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Updating the link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html